# handling ruby octals with a leading zero

Tags: ruby, numbers, integer, zero

The result of outputting

```
puts (030).to_i
```

is `24` - due to Ruby's octal representation.  If `030` is a fixnum (and not a string), is there a way to convert it to 30?
( Performing `(030).to_s` will also return `'24'`. )

Comment: This is something very basic in the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number with leading zero is octal number.

```
030 == 3 * 8 ** 1 + 0 * 8 ** 0
```

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  What is the best way to deal with a leading zero?  To remove it?  Or is there a conversion method that will treat it as 30?

Comment: If `030` is string, you can convert to Fixnum by `'030'.to_i`.

Comment: `030` is interpreted as octal in a number of languages, including JavaScript and C-derived languages.

Comment: A leading zero **unless** that leading zero is immediately followed by an `x`/`X` (hexadecimal) or `b`/`B` (binary).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at how you end up in a situation where you have to convert `030` to `30`.

If you take any kind of user input, you probably, at the moment you receive the user input, start with a string `"030"` and then calling `"030".to_i` will give you the desired result of `30`.

It's probably "cleaner" to fix your code to use string to int conversion as opposed to end up with an octal and then go back to an integer by stripping leading 0's.